# "cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}gcc" when trying to use WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

So, I'm trying to use "Windows.h" to output unicode characters on console with wchar_t*, and I found on internet that this is the code I'm supposed to use:

```
wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

   while(1) {
      screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight - 1] = '\0';
       WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);

   
   }
```

However, when I try to compile, I get this error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}gcc

I'm compiling with mingw64 and I'm using this command:

```
            "-std=c++20",
            "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
            "-L",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\lib",
            "-I",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\include",
            "-l",
                "mingw32"   ,"-l",
                "SDL2main"  ,"-l",
                "SDL2",
            "-o",
                "main",
```

(I'm technically also using SDL2, but I don't need it at the moment)

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried using `std::wcout` ?

Comment: The Internet has `#define UNICODE` in effect.  Put it before the #include of windows.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` is a macro of `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW` or `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA` depends on the charset compiler option.

`WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW` accepts LPCWSTR (a.k.a `const WCHAR*` a.k.a `const wchar_t *`, or `const unsigned short *` if wchar_t is not supported by the compiler) as parameter.

`WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA` accepts LPCSTR (a.k.a `const char *`) as parameter.

So, checkout your compiling settings, and make sure which version you are actually calling, and define your `screen` as the right type.

If not sure or you want support both, you could use TCHAR string/buffer instead. `TCHAR` is a macro of `WCHAR` or `char` depends on the same compiler option. And LPCSTR/LPSTR is macros of the pointer types.

Comment: Or, just call WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW directly and forget the compiler's charset option

Comment: tried to change WriteConsoleOutputCharacter to WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW, and it worked. Then I managed to change the charset in the compiler options to unicode, and now it also works when I use WriteConsoleOutputCharacter. Thank you!